# After displaying a Carousel card in Dailogflow, I want to select one of the lists by voice operation

Tags: carousel, dialogflow-es

Tell us about Dailogflow.
In the settings of Intents, it was set to display the Carousel card of GoogleAssistant in the response.

I've been able to display the carousel card, but I want to select one of these cards by voice action and open the URL set for that card.

I couldn't find it in the reference, so please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

If this is not possible, is there any other way to achieve equivalent content?

I don't have good English.Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use follow up intent. So when you are displaying a list or carousel card and you want to make this selection by click and as well as by user utterance. You have to add two follow up intent one for selection one for text utterance.

**consider below example:** ShippingOption intent displays a list and that can be selectable as well as get the response by user utterance.

[image]

**app.js**

```
intentMap.set("shippingOptionIntent", shippingOptionIntent);
intentMap.set("shippingOptionIntent - select", shippingOptionIntentSelect);
intentMap.set("shippingOptionIntentChoose", shippingOptionIntentChoose);
```

Now set the utterance for followup intent:

[image]

Where another followup intent responsible for user selection by clicking on the option. It has the google assistant option event.

[image]

So, in this way you can handle both types of responses.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
It seems that you can select one of the lists according to the proposal you have proposed. It was helpful.
However, is there anything that opens and displays a Web page as a response of Dialogflow?

Comment: Probably not, but You can send a link in response, that the user has to click that will open in web view or user default browser. You can not directly open a web page during a conversation, it because of user experience and more security purpose you can not. It is the same as fishing links in email. You can send but its end-user choice to open it or not otherwise, this feature is miss used, that is why it won't allow to directly open a web page.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.
Certainly, given security issues, I should avoid building that behavior.
Thank you for teaching me carefully!!!